# What is a lattice regularization scheme?

Tags: band-structure, model-hamiltonians, tight-binding

I am trying to read this paper

Chiral Anomaly from Strain-Induced Gauge Fields in Dirac and Weyl Semimetals
https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.041021

In section II the authors introduce a matrix hamiltonian derived from first principles calculation that models the band structure. Later, in order to introduce gradients in hopping amplitudes, they use "lattice regularization" to get a different hamiltonian notated $H^{lat}$.
What is the process to get from equation (2.1) to (2.3)? What does this hamiltonian operate on and what are the terms $\tau^x,\tau^y,\tau^z$?

I'd appreciate a reference where this process is explained, as a search for relevant keywords gave nothing.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! Sorry that it took me so long to welcome you! I already gave you the +1 long ago though. Have you figured out that answer to this question? Are you still actively needing the answer? Please update us!